# Uploading data with psycopg2 and python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, psql

With the next cmds I am trying to upload a csv file where columns are separated by tabs and sometimes null values can be assigned to a column.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", 
                        port="5432", 
                        user="postgres",
                        password="somepwd",
                        database="mydb", 
                        options="-c search_path=dbo")
```

...

```
cur = conn.cursor()

with open(opath, "r") as opath_file:
    next(opath_file)   # skip the header row
    cur.copy_from(opath_file, table_name[3:], null='', columns=cols.split(','))
```

- cols has a string with the column names separated by ','
- the table with name  table_name[3:] belongs to the dbo schema

This code runs, no error is reported but no data is uploaded. The owner of the db is postgres.

Any ideas?

Comment: You haven't provided the INSERT statement that you are (or should be) using

Comment: but, isn't cur.copy_from the one that inserts?

Comment: Ah, so it is. Sorry. Two problems with your call to it: #1 the `.split()` method is returning a list not a tuple, so you need to pass `columns=tuple(cols.split(","))`, and #2 the separate defaults to tab, so you need to specify `sep=','`

Comment: @JamesMcPherson, you don't need to convert to a `tuple`, per documentation [COPY](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from): "columns – iterable with name of the columns to import.  ...". A list qualifies as an iterable and I use them in `copy_from` on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

Would you believe me if the problem was I needed to run

conn.commit()

after the cur.copy_from cmd?